# Do I need a specific kind of patent lawyer to handle a software patent?

Tags: software

Do I need a specific kind of patent lawyer to handle a software patent?

It seems to me that the advanced computer terminology involved in patenting software would require a patent lawyer that specializes in the area. Is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no requirement in using a lawyer, but unless you have the expertise you would probably not want tot do it yourself.

What you want is a person intimately familiar with the process and the required way for formatting and wording a patent -- the rules are strict unless what you file is a provisional patent.

Such a person could be a lawyer, but he does not have to be a lawyer.   As with all lawyers they each specialize in certain area (tax, criminal matters, etc) and so the lawyer you would need would have to specialize in patent and be knowledgeable about the subject matter you want to patent.

Answer (score 2):

It is important to get someone comfortable and experienced with the technology involved in your invention but there are no official labels for different types of patent lawyers.